# Giving background music to a webpage

Tags: javascript, background-music

```
   var musicsrc="jyothir2.mp3";
if (navigator.appName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer")
document.write('<bgsound src='+'"'+musicsrc+'"'+' loop="infinite">')
else 
document.write('<embed src=\"'+musicsrc+'\" hidden="true" border="0" width="20" height="20" autostart="true" loop="infinite">')
```

friends my javascript( for background music) codes  is producing a continuous music in IE but the music is not continuous in other browsers.. can anybody tell me why is it so?

Comment: Eeeewwwww!!! Please, don't play music on your web pages. PLEASE!

Comment: Makes me thankful my volume remains muted until I need it.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2472736/uninterrupted-mp3-play-on-a-website

Comment: Downvoted. This is one of the best ways to ensure that visitors leave your site quickly and never come back.

Comment: @CylonCat -1 That's not a good reason to downvote the question!  Any number of reasons why he might need to include background music.  This is a technical question, not a style or design question.

Comment: @Kirk, technical questions often mask larger questions about not only style and design, but also requirements and the overall sucess or failure of a web site. A good developer should be aware of that, and should push back on requirements that are self-defeating, such as this one.

Comment: @CylonCat, I agree and I like the comments which do that - but without knowing the requirement, I don't agree that it warrants a downvote.

Comment: The poster may not actually be putting music on the site, but some kind of ambient background sounds. Also, people are often told what to do at work and don't have a say in the matter, as in my case. Personally I wouldn't do it, but when the guy who pays me tells me to, I should do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Worth It?

It is well worth considering whether playing continuous background music to all your visitors is something you actually want to do. Many people feel it is a bit of an invasion for sites to just decide what they will hear. This is particularly a problem for people who may be using their computers to listen to their own choice of music. It also adds significantly to the bandwidth used by your site. Be sure this is something visitors will find of value before going ahead with it.

#### The Solution

If you decide this *is* something you and your visitors want and will appreciate, the solution is simple. For the non-IE (`embed` element) version, you should set the loop attribute to either `true` or `false`. Setting it to `true` will cause it to loop indefinitely, and setting it to `false` will not. It will not know what to do with the value of `infinite`, so it is most likely interpreting it as the default, `false`.

In addition, I have also noticed you are escaping your double-quotes with a backslash. You don't need to do this as you are already using single-quote-delimited strings.

Comment: Wow, I wouldn't have thought someone on stackoverflow would actually recommend `document.write()`-ing `bgsound` s

Comment: I am not *recommending* anything. I am simply giving him the answer to the question - why did it not work.

Answer (score 1):

Use **bgsound** tag for IE and 
Use **embed** tag for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to play sound on a web page is through Flash. If you don't want to create a Flash movie just for playing a sound, there's a really nice library called [SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) which allows you to play sounds directly through JavaScript (it creates Flash objects without you having to know about them).

Alternatively, you could use the new [`<audio>`](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/video.html#audio) tag, but it isn't supported on widely used and stoneage-like browsers such as Internet Explorer. So, if you need to support such browsers you should go with SoundManager2. Otherwise, use of the `<audio>` tag is recommended, and, much nicer :)

Comment: +1 for suggesting Flash. The really nice thing about it is that it can be easily blocked :)

Answer (score -1):

```
    <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
<!-- 
var filename="Welcome To The Club.mp3";

    document.writeln ('<EMBED SRC="' + filename + '" AUTOSTART=TRUE loop=TRUE WIDTH=144 HEIGHT=60><P>');

// -->
</SCRIPT>
```